# Revisiting the decision on Google Analytics

Tags: discussion, scope

Way back in the early days of the site there was a discussion about whether questions about Google Analytics were on- or off-topic.

- [Are questions about Google Analytics on- or off- topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/are-questions-about-google-analytics-on-or-off-topic)

The accepted answer (and, for a time) the answer with the highest score was that they were on-topic.

The votes have since reversed, but since there's so few of them I don't think that can really be a measure of community consensus.

After four+ years though, it seems to me pretty clear that questions about Google Analytics are a poor fit here. Sure, the administrative functions of Google Analytics are a web app, but by-and-large the questions are about how to manipulate and analyze the data, *not* how to use the app.

Have a look at some of them: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics

Meanwhile, over at [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), they also have questions about Google Analytics that are the same sort of questions, but they get more and better answers: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics
(There's also at least 10 times more questions than here.)

I think we should change policy and make Google Analytics off-topic by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have a tendency to migrate pretty much all Google Analytics questions to Webmasters Stack Exchange, so your proposal does hold merit.

I'll update the FAQ and other pages in few days reflecting this